# SQL ERROR: ORA-00904: "TIMESTAMP": INVALID IDENTIFIER

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hi I have created a table and wanting to add data now, I have timestamp as the data type and I am getting errors anyone can help me out?

```
CREATE TABLE Production(
ProductionID INT PRIMARY KEY,
ProductionName VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
ProductionDescription VARCHAR2(250) NOT NULL,
ProductionDate DATE NOT NULL,
ProductionTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
ProductionTypeID INT NOT NULL,
NoOfHelpers CHAR(1) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO PRODUCTION(PRODUCTIONID, PRODUCTIONNAME, PRODUCTIONDATE, PRODUCTIONTIME, PRODUCTIONTYPEID, NOOFHELPERS)
VALUES(1,'THELONDONSINFONIA', TO_DATE('31-AUG-2004','DD-MON-YYYY'), TIMESTAMP('2014-05-05 20:15:00'), 1, 7);
```

I am using oracle sql developer to create the database

this is the error :

> Error starting at line : 10 in command -
>
> INSERT INTO PRODUCTION(PRODUCTIONID, PRODUCTIONNAME, PRODUCTIONDATE, PRODUCTIONTIME, PRODUCTIONTYPEID, NOOFHELPERS) 
>   VALUES(1,'THELONDONSINFONIA', TO_DATE('31-AUG-2004','DD-MON-YYYY'), TIMESTAMP('2014-05-05 20:15:00'), 1, 7)
>
> Error at Command Line : 11 Column : 69
>
> Error report -
>
> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "TIMESTAMP": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>
> *Cause:
>
> *Action:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timestamp` isn't a function where you need to use `(` and `)`, it is a prefix just like `n` is to indicate a `varchar` is actually containing Unicode text (so a `varchar2` or `nvarchar`).

So don't use this:

```
timestamp('2014-05-05 20:15:00')
```

But this:

```
timestamp'2014-05-05 20:15:00'
```

Comment: Also need to insert values in ProductionDescription since it is not null column, he doesn't included this  in insert statement